# Как сделать у полей ACF options возможность выбора админом, на каких страницах их выводить?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

На сайте будет попап, который должен появляться на выбранных страницах.
Другими словами, внутри условия

```
<? if( is_page( array( 11, 22, 33, 44 ) ) ) { ?>
    // Код попапа
<? } ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы админ мог выбирать эти страницы через ACF options.
Для этого я создал поле Объект записи со следующими настройками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получаю айдишники страниц через код

```
<?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): ?><?php echo $post_object->ID; ?>,<?php endforeach; ?>
```

И тут мои навыки в php закончились. Как бы этот foreach поместить внутрь array?
Причем желательно таким образом, чтобы после последнего ID запятой бы не было.

Comment: Замените "Объект записи" на "ID записи", вам вернет просто массив ID, который Вы сможете подставить прямо в условие `if(is_page())`

Comment: Да, прежде, чем начать усложнять, я пробовал этот вариант. Но не сработало. ни если напрямую писать `the_field( 'na_kakih_straniczah', 'option' );`, ни если делать через переменную и её выводить `$na_kakih_straniczah = get_field( 'na_kakih_straniczah', 'option' ); is_page( array( $na_kakih_straniczah ) )`

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump(get_field( 'na_kakih_straniczah', 'option' ));` и посмотрите что Вам приходит. Если объект, замените в настройках поля на ID, как я и написал.

Comment: Ну и это должно было выглядеть вот так `is_page($na_kakih_straniczah)`, потому что возвращает массив.

Comment: Так я это всё делал изначально, я же об этом и написал. Не работает. var_dump всё выводит правильно. Но если положить в переменную, то результата нет. Поэтому и начал усложнять, делая через объект записи.

Comment: Да, но Вы написали что пробовали вот так `is_page( array( $na_kakih_straniczah ) )` но такая запись работать не будет, оно должно выглядеть вот так `is_page($na_kakih_straniczah)`, разницу не замечаете?

Comment: Ха! Действительно, не заметил разницы) Сейчас заметил, попробовал - да, всё работает. Но как? Ведь если там перечисляются несколько страниц, надо указывать `arrray` - на wp-kama.ru/function/is_page так написано. Или тут реально выводится только один айдишник - тот, который соответствует текущей странице - или не выводится ничего? Хотя если не выводится ничего, то должно просто сработать условие `is_page` для всех страниц. Не понимаю :-( Но за помощь спасибо, да, теперь всё работает как надо))

Comment: Решением вашу подсказку нельзя отметить? Т.к. это комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: Ну как, `get_field('na_kakih_straniczah', 'option')` -- само по себе уже является массивом, потому его там и не нужно указывать) Просто Вам фактически по-умолчанию возвращает то что нужно. Можете просто составить условие `if (!empty($na_kakih_straniczah) && is_page($na_kakih_straniczah))` чтобы не выводилось для всех. Грубо говоря, Вы проверите выбраны ли страницы и если да, то для выбраных выводить попап.